# Liberty Server: Data source configuration

Tags: datasource, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to configure Datasource on Liberty Server 20.0.0.9.
I'm referring to the following instructions:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-configuring-default-data-source

This is my server.xml

Features added:

```
<feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
<feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
```

Library configuration

```
<library description="My shared library" id="MyLib" name="MyLib">
        <fileset dir="${usr.extension.dir}/lib" id="MyLibTAI" includes="MyLibTAI-1.0.4.jar db2jcc-db2jcc4.jar"/>
    </library>
```

Datasource

```
<dataSource id="defaultDS" jndiName="jdbc/defautlDS">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MyLib"/>
        <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="DBXV01" serverName="192.33.112.21" portNumber="70080"/>
        <containerAuthData user="myuser" password="mypwd"></containerAuthData>
    </dataSource>
```

In my code I'm trying to refer to Datasource in different ways:

```
@Resource(name="defaultsDS") // I also tried name="jdbc/defaultDS"

or

ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/picoDS"); // Name not found exception
```

What I'm missing?
Any help appreciated
Thank you

Comment: 2 issues: 1 Are you trying to use 'Deafult datasource? - in that case it should be called `dataSource id="DefaultDataSource"` as in doc you are refering. 2. Are you using it in TAI or web app? If in TAI then you cannot use `java:comp` and you need to lookup using jndi name like `lookup("jdbc/defautlDS")` and then cannot use default one but your own.

Comment: thank you Gas.
I solved with lookup("jdbc/defaultDS")

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a lookup of the jndiName configured in server.xml (as suggested in the other answer), you need to be aware that it is not using container managed authentication and thus the `containerAuthData` that you specified in server.xml for the `dataSource` is not being used.  You were on the right track the first time in using a resource reference, and here is how to do that correctly:

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/defautlDS")
DataSource datasource;
```

Similar, you can use the Resource annotation to define a name for the resource reference that can be looked up in java:comp,

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/defautlDS", name = "java:comp/env/picoDS")
DataSource datasource;
```

after which you can successfully do:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/picoDS");
```

I added the `/env` to the resource reference name in the above to better follow standards.

In both of the above, I used `defautlDS` to match the unusual spelling of the `jndiName` value from your example, which might itself be a typo. Make sure it is consistent in both places in order for it to work.

By using the resource reference, you are able to get container managed authentication (container managed is the default for resource reference lookups) and so you end up using the user and password from conatinerAuthData of your config.  If not using the resource reference, then you get application managed authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I solved, as suggested by Gas in comments, using

```
ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("jdbc/defaultDS");
```